# How to set relative path instead of absolute

Tags: qt, qml

I am using Qt Quick Application project in QT 5.2.1 in Linux Mint 13 and I want use relative path to my audio files, which are located in sounds folder of my project folder.
Here is my

> main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Audio{
        id: sound
        source: "sounds/1.mp3"  //doesn't work
        source: "file:../sounds/1.mp3" //also doesn't work
        source: "file:/home/vlado/Qt projects/test521/sounds/1.mp3" //this works
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            sound.play()
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Play Sound")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Doesn't work means, that there is following error:

> GStreamer; Unable to play - ""  Error: "No URI set"

As you can see, everything is OK, if I use absolute path, but I would like to deploy this application and installation folder then will be different. That's why I want to use relative path.
Here is my

> test521.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

Here is

> my main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///qml/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

How to set relative path instead of absolute?

**Edit:** Solution for QML: [how to specify image file path relative to application folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549708/qml-how-to-specify-image-file-path-relative-to-application-folder) doesn't work for me.

Comment: See: [QML: how to specify image file path relative to application folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549708/qml-how-to-specify-image-file-path-relative-to-application-folder).

Comment: @agold but in accepted solution line  engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("applicationDirPath", QGuiApplication::applicationDirPath()); gives me an error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QQmlContext'

Comment: You should add `#include <QQmlContext>`, see [Error: forward declaration of 'class QQmlContext'](https://forum.qt.io/topic/30025/solved-error-forward-declaration-of-class-qqmlcontext/2).

Comment: @agold QQmlContext error solved. Thanks! But now with line source: applicationDirPath + "/../resources/sounds/1.mp3" I still have the error: GStreamer; Unable to play - "" 
Error: "No URI set" The same error is, if I change this line to source: applicationDirPath + "file:../sounds/1.mp3"

Comment: Put the path after "`file:`", thus: `source: "file: "+applicationDirPath+"/../sounds/1.mp3"`

Comment: No. It doesn't work. It gives me an error: GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file: /home/vlado/Qt projects/build-test521-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/../sounds/1.mp3" 
Error: "Could not open resource for reading." 
 I updated line to source: "file:"+applicationDirPath+"/sounds/1.mp3" and also  I have error: GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/vlado/Qt projects/build-test521-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/sounds/1.mp3" 
Error: "Resource not found." I think it is because qt looks for 1.mp3 in debug folder and there is no such file.

Comment: As a side note you can use your sounds, images etc as resources just like the qml files. Then just use the qrc path to access your files.

Comment: @Vladimir: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305646/video-wont-play) they comment about a [bug which is fixed in Qt 5.5](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33400).

Comment: @juzzlin it also doesn't work. If I use source:"qrc:/1.mp3" and 1.mp3 is added in Resources I get Error: "No valid frames found before end of stream"

Comment: @agold with Qt 5.5 it's worse then with 5.2.1, because when I am starting to run project I get defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"

Comment: Be sure you have the QtMediaplayer compiled, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966150/qtquick-cannot-playback-any-video-on-embedded-linux

Comment: @agold I did not understand how to compile QtMultimediaplayer. Can you advise to me?